# Remove duplicate subcategory block items from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

```
    <category link-id="681" link-handle="package-products" value="Package products">
        <entry id="1077" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
            <sub-category>
                <item handle="pens">Pens</item>
                <item handle="refills-pens">Refills : Pens</item>
            </sub-category>
        </entry>
        <entry id="1075" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
            <sub-category>
                <item handle="pencil">Pencil</item>
                <item handle="refills-pencil">Refills : Pencil</item>
            </sub-category>
        </entry>
        <entry id="1073" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
            <sub-category>
                <item handle="pencil">Pencil</item>
                <item handle="refills-pencil">Refills : Pencil</item>
            </sub-category>
        </entry>
        <entry id="1050" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
            <sub-category>
                <item handle="marker">Marker</item>
                <item handle="refills-marker">Refills : Marker</item>
            </sub-category>
        </entry>
```

I want to remove duplication of 3rd block from sub category for output.
Please help me on this.
I want output as :

```
Pens

Refills : Pens

Pencil

Refills : Pencils

Marker

Refills : Marker
```

Comment: can you post the XSLT (what you have tried), and always post the simple and complete XML for testing (here, it is not well formed XML).

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: @DanielHaley : 1.0 version of XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This: (XSLT version 2)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="kItemHandle" match="entry" use="sub-category/item"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="category">
    <xsl:for-each select="entry[count(. | key('kItemHandle', sub-category/item[1])[1])=1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="sub-category/item[1]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sub-category/item[2]"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping! Now I have question is why and what is the use of this statement "<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>" also I have multiple categories means more than 3 they are repeating too so can you suggest how to make it dynamically sorry to ask such questions but I am really new to XSLT.

Comment: <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text> is for NEWLINE character (line break). For multiple catogories, can you try first at your own, now "ENTRY" is multiple right, like that alter to the "CATOGORY". I will suggest soon. If possible raise a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option that uses XSLT 2.0 grouping ([`xsl:for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)). The option proposed by Rudramuni TP can actually be used as an XSLT 1.0 option.

**XML Input**

```
<category link-id="681" link-handle="package-products" value="Package products">
    <entry id="1077" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="pens">Pens</item>
            <item handle="refills-pens">Refills : Pens</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1075" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="pencil">Pencil</item>
            <item handle="refills-pencil">Refills : Pencil</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1073" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="pencil">Pencil</item>
            <item handle="refills-pencil">Refills : Pencil</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1050" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="marker">Marker</item>
            <item handle="refills-marker">Refills : Marker</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
</category>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="entry/sub-category" group-by="item[1]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]"/>                
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Pens

Refills : Pens

Pencil

Refills : Pencil

Marker

Refills : Marker
```

Answer (score 0):

This for Multiple 'catogory':

Input XML:

```
<root>
<category link-id="681" link-handle="package-products" value="Package products">
    <entry id="1077" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="pens">Pens</item>
            <item handle="refills-pens">Refills : Pens</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1075" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="pencil">Pencil</item>
            <item handle="refills-pencil">Refills : Pencil</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1073" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="pencil">Pencil</item>
            <item handle="refills-pencil">Refills : Pencil</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1050" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="marker">Marker</item>
            <item handle="refills-marker">Refills : Marker</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
</category>

<category link-id="681" link-handle="package-products" value="Package products">
    <entry id="1077" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="pens">Pens</item>
            <item handle="refills-pens">Refills : Pens</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1075" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="pencil">Pencil</item>
            <item handle="refills-pencil">Refills : Pencil</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1073" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="pencil">Pencil</item>
            <item handle="refills-pencil">Refills : Pencil</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1050" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="marker">Marker</item>
            <item handle="refills-marker">Refills : Marker</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
    <entry id="1052" images="1" products="1" brands="1">
        <sub-category>
            <item handle="paper">Paper</item>
            <item handle="refills-paper">Refills : Paper</item>
        </sub-category>
    </entry>
</category>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="kItemHandle" match="entry" use="sub-category/item"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="category/entry[count(. | key('kItemHandle', sub-category/item)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="sub-category/item[1]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sub-category/item[2]"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

Pens
  Refills : Pens
  Pencil
  Refills : Pencil
  Marker
  Refills : Marker
  Paper
  Refills : Paper